# require a certian number of checkboxes to be selected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to require 3 checkboxes from a group of checkboxes to be required to be selected.

I've been able to restrict the selections to no more than 3, which is great, but I need to also require that at least 3 out of the group be selected.

Here's my example HTML:

```
      <div class="pricing-levels-3">
      <p><strong>Which levels would you like? (Select 3 Levels)</strong></p>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike1">Level 1<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Bike2">Level 2<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Bike3">Level 3<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle4" value="Bike4">Level 4<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle5" value="Bike5">Level 5<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle6" value="Bike6">Level 6<br>
      <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle7" value="Bike7">Level 7<br>
      </div>
```

And jQuery:

```
    var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you'd want to check this on submit, so in your submit function just use  `if($(this).siblings(':checked').length < limit)`

Comment: why not do this with required="required" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var len = $(".single-checkbox:checked").length; // get length (amount)
```

Then you can check if three checkboxes are checked.

```
if (len == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var limit = 3, checked = 0;

$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(event) {

    checked = $('input.single-checkbox:checked').length;

    if(checked >= limit) {
        this.checked = false; // OR event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    if( checked < limit )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('...');
    }
});
```